Refactor component with Signals
I'm using Angular 17 and started now to apply Signals and whatever I can to in future versions, as 19 says, make zoneless angular applications and etc.
So, here I am, but, I'm confused to how apply some refactors, like for this list product component, so this is some of the questions I have trying to change the code:
We have the bindProducts/brands to fill the variables, so I see I can use toSignal() to get the pure array as signal, but this leads me to the following problem:

What if I want to remade the GET? How I will rebind the products and brands signal arrays?
How I will use this products/brands from the signal to fill my Material datasource.data with this data? (considering angular doesn't encourage using effect()). I was thinking about computed() but this is used to create a variable readonly signal, not just do something when some signal value change

Here my current component (resumed)
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-products',
  templateUrl: './list-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-products.component.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MaterialModule, FormsModule, ButtonComponent, RouterModule, ResultComponent],
})
export class ListProductsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Product>([]);
  searchSubject = new Subject<string>();

  productFilter = '';
  brandsSelectionFilter: number[] = [];

  products: Product[] = [];
  brands: Brand[] = [];

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(
    private productsService: ProductsService,
    private branchService: BranchService,
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    private router: Router,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.productFilterFn;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchSubject.pipe(debounceTime(300)).subscribe(() => this.applyProductFilter());
    this.bindBrandsAndProducts();
  }



  bindBrandsAndProducts() {
    forkJoin([this.branchService.getAllBrands(), this.productsService.getAllProducts()]).subscribe(
      ([brands, products]) => {
        products.forEach((p) =>
          p.imageReferences.forEach((img) => (img.url += `?timestamp=${new Date().getTime()}`))
        );

        this.products = products.slice();
        this.dataSource.data = products.slice();
        this.brands = brands.slice();
      }
    );
  }

  private bindProducts(): void {
    this.productsService.getAllProducts().subscribe((products) => {
      this.products = products.slice();
      this.dataSource.data = products.slice();
    });
  }

  applyProductFilter(): void {
    let filteredProducts = this.products.slice();

    if (this.brandsSelectionFilter.length > 0) {
      filteredProducts = this.products.filter((product) => {
        const productBrandTypes = product.brands.map((b) => b.brandType);
        return productBrandTypes.some((type) => this.brandsSelectionFilter.includes(type));
      });
    }

    this.dataSource.data = filteredProducts;
    this.dataSource.filter = this.productFilter.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

  productFilterFn(data: Product, filter: string): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}

And I started with this:
  readonly #productsService = inject(ProductsService);
  readonly #branchService = inject(BranchService);
  readonly #dialog = inject(MatDialog);
  readonly #router = inject(Router);
  readonly #toastr = inject(ToastrService);

  readonly paginator = viewChild.required(MatPaginator);

  readonly dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Product>([]);
  searchSubject = new Subject<string>();

  productFilter = '';
  brandsSelectionFilter: number[] = [];

  products = toSignal(this.#productsService.getAllProducts(), { initialValue: [] });
  brands = toSignal(this.#branchService.getAllBrands(), { initialValue: [] });

  constructor() {
    afterNextRender(() => {
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator();
      this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.productFilterFn;
    });
  }

But again, how would I do these changes? I'm thinking I will have a totally new code flow changing that, so it's a little bit confusing to get all of that changes
Edit: I decided to put products as a signal of product[], and then just created a bind products method to bind to it, and then call my filter method that already applies the datasource.data and etc.
readonly products = signal<Product[]>([]);

private bindProducts(): void {
    this.#productsService
      .getAllProducts()
      .pipe(
        tap((products) => {
          products.forEach(({ imageReferences }) =>
            imageReferences.forEach((i) => (i.url += `?timestamp=${new Date().getTime()}`))
          );
        }),
        takeUntilDestroyed(this.#destroyRef)
      )
      .subscribe((products) => {
        this.products.set(products.slice());
        this.applyProductFilters();
      });
  }

  private applyProductFilters(): void {
    //filter code...
    this.dataSource.data = productsByBrands;
    this.dataSource.filter = search.trim().toLowerCase();
  }


I tried angular signal for a year, here is my approach for applying signal and partly getting rid of Observable in the component file. Let me use some refactoring to your example.
Question 1

What if I want to remade the GET? How I will rebind the products and brands signal arrays?

// product.service.ts

export class ProductService {
  private readonly http = inject(HttpClient);
  private readonly innerData = toSignal([]);

  readonly data = computed(() => this.innerData());

  getAllProducts() {
    this.http.get('/products').subscribe((response) => {
      this.innerData.set(response.data);
    });
  }
}

// my-component.ts

export class MyComponent {
  private readonly productService = inject(ProductService);

  readonly products = this.productService.data;

  initData() {
    this.productService.getAllProducts();
    // Init something
  }

  reBindData() {
    this.productService.getAllProducts();
  }
}

Explanation: I created innerData as a signal to manage the data within the service and then derived a computed signal, data, from innerData. The reason for not using innerData directly was to implement Encapsulation, ensuring better control and abstraction over the internal state.
Question 2

How I will use this products/brands from the signal to fill my Material datasource.data with this data? (considering angular doesn't encourage using effect()). I was thinking about computed() but this is used to create a variable readonly signal, not just do something when some signal value change

If you need to perform side effects when a signal's value changes but prefer not to use effect, you can convert the signal to an Observable using toObservable and then subscribe to the resulting Observable.
export class MyComponent {
  private readonly productService = inject(ProductService);

  readonly products = this.productService.data;

  readonly products$ = toObservable(this.products);

  constructor() {
    this.products$.subscribe(() => {
      // Do something when products change
    })
  }

  initData() {
    this.productService.getAllProducts();
    // Init something
  }

  reBindData() {
    this.productService.getAllProducts();
  }
}

Hope it can help!!

Hi, thank you Mike, so much, seriously.
About the first question: I was wondering about this innerData in the service itself, but... usually I have more than one get of products, I think it can become confusing to handle different gets and having only one innerData for they all or just for the "main" get, what do you think?
And second: as involve with your changes in the service, but, the toObservable(this.products) is going to listen to changes and update the observable if we call some of the rebind methods? And It will not duplicate the get call, right?

If you can look at my question edit, I put some of the code I wrote before, as I thought it was a good approach
